How do I fix this AttributeError when I am using try to use Zipline to ingest
I installed anaconda and to create a python environment in version 3.6.
The following is what I did and ended with an AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.indexing' has no attribute 'get_indexers_list'. The following is after I had installed anaconda and created a python environment.
(zipline_env) jasimkhan@Jasims-MBP ~ % export QUANDL_API_KEY=8jXRMHjfVv2UGJ8vXU1J
(zipline_env) jasimkhan@Jasims-MBP ~ % zipline ingest -b quandl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/zipline_env/bin/zipline", line 7, in <module>
    from zipline.__main__ import main
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/zipline_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipline/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import finance
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/zipline_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipline/finance/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import execution, trading
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/zipline_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipline/finance/trading.py", line 20, in <module>
    from zipline.utils.pandas_utils import normalize_date
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/zipline_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipline/utils/pandas_utils.py", line 223, in <module>
    '_' + name for (name, _) in pd.core.indexing.get_indexers_list()
AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.indexing' has no attribute 'get_indexers_list'


I didn't try anything as I couldn't find information on this at the moment. I wasn't expecting any errors but it gave me one. Please could someone help me solve this issue?
